# iptables ignores other rules after add last rule

Tags: iptables, forwarding

I have written these rules in `iptables`:

```
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -p icmp -m limit --limit 1/hour --limit-burst 5000 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -p udp -m limit --limit 1/hour --limit-burst 200 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -m limit --limit 1/hour --limit-burst 200 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m limit --limit 1/hour --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j limitlog
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j limitlog
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j limitlog
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j limitlog
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j limitlog
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -j limitlog
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j limitlog
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5123 -j limitlog
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 5123 -j limitlog
-A limitlog -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j LOG --log-prefix "HTTPS z HP: "
-A limitlog -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m limit --limit 1/hour --limit-burst 900 -j ACCEPT
-A limitlog -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j LOG --log-prefix "HTTP z HP: "
-A limitlog -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 1/hour --limit-burst 960 -j ACCEPT
-A limitlog -i eth1 -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j LOG --log-prefix "DNS z HP: "
-A limitlog -i eth1 -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m limit --limit 1/hour --limit-burst 360 -j ACCEPT
-A limitlog -i eth1 -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j LOG --log-prefix "NTP z HP: "
-A limitlog -i eth1 -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -m limit --limit 1/hour --limit-burst 300 -j ACCEPT
-A limitlog -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j LOG --log-prefix "FTP z HP: "
-A limitlog -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m limit --limit 1/hour --limit-burst 900 -j ACCEPT
-A limitlog -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -j LOG --log-prefix "FTP DATA z HP: "
-A limitlog -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -m limit --limit 1/hour --limit-burst 900 -j ACCEPT
-A limitlog -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j LOG --log-prefix "SSH/SCP z HP: "
-A limitlog -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m limit --limit 1/hour --limit-burst 900 -j ACCEPT
-A limitlog -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5123 -j LOG --log-prefix "5123TCP z HP: "
-A limitlog -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5123 -m limit --limit 1/hour --limit-burst 300 -j ACCEPT
-A limitlog -i eth1 -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 5123 -j LOG --log-prefix "5123UDP z HP: "
-A limitlog -i eth1 -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 5123 -m limit --limit 1/hour --limit-burst 300 -j ACCEPT
```

`eth0` is the external network and `eth1` is the internal network. It works correct, but if I add this rule:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j DROP
```

all previous rules are ignored and traffic ends on this last rule. I do not understand... Why? If I remove this rule and modify rules in my chain `limitlog` for example from `ACCEPT` to `DROP` it works too.

Comment: What do you mean by "all previous rules are ignored"? What kind of packet behaves how and what do you expect instead and why?

Comment: Use `iptables -S` to list rules instead of `iptables -L`, its output is much more precise (and arguably more readable).

Comment: @HaukeLaging it is because all packets from internal network are dropped, it includes all packets from machine, which is behind this iptables firewall. So HTTP, HTTPS, DNS communication and etc is dropped. If I remove last rule it works correctly. I need restrict comunication from machine which is behind iptables only few destination ports and monitor it with these rules...

Comment: @BatchyX I added it.

Comment: @Mato But that is exactly the meaning of the rule, isn't it? "Drop everything that has not been accepted already." I asked you why you expect something different. I rephrase that: Which earlier rule should be matched in your opinion? As BatchyX already pointed out: The limit options are quite stupid.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Thanks. I am sorry, yes limit options are stupid. It is my first work with iptables. Can you post some operative and efective simple example for one destination port restriction as 80. I need restrict network traffic from machine behind iptables firewall only for initialized connections. And these connections have to allow only if have destination port 80, 443 etc... And I need apply limit for packet flow too, which prevent for example DDoS attack...

Answer (score 2):

Your limits are quite a bit aggressive. I don't see the point of having rules that only accept one packet per hour. You might have set high burstiness, but the bucket is only recharged by one every hour, and only if you actually received less than one packet per hour.

The worst part is that these limits are applied for ALL packet, since you do not accept them if they are part of an established/related conntrack state.

The statistics in the `-L` dump suggest that it is not the problem, but maybe you made the dump before your tests. (you can include statistics on `-S` by adding `-v`).

Unrelated: there are many way your ruleset can be simplified.  If the `limitlog` chain is only called by `-i eth1 -o eth0`, you can omit all `-i` and `-o` in it.

Comment: Thank you. My limit options are really stupid. It is my first work with iptables. As I write above can you post some example for one destination port restriction as 80 please. I need restrict network traffic from machine behind iptables firewall only for initialized connections. And these connections have to allow only if have destination port 80, 443 etc... All other connections from this machine have to dropped. And I need apply limit for packet flow and log it too, which prevent for example DDoS attack...

Answer (score 0):

You need the `state RELATED,ESTABLISHED` rule for traffic from external to internal and you need one or more rules for allowing internal traffic to external. You can either allow everything or allow certain services only.

I find it confusing to to `ACCEPT`s in a chain called *`log`.

Furthermore it may be useful to have a rule for `TCPMSS` for internal traffic to the outside:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
```

And you should think about it what you want to log and why.

Comment: Thanks. So for example if I want allow only initialized connections to destination port 80 from machine behind iptables firewall and I want log and restrict it, can I use something like this please? (eth0 -external network, eth1 - internal network):

Comment: `-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`
`-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j LOG --log-prefix "HTTP:"`
`-A limitlog -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 900/hour -j ACCEPT`
`-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j DROP`

Comment: @Mato You should avoid `-i eth0 -o eth1` in the `--state RELATED,ESTABLISHED` rule. Otherwise every outgoing packet of a connection gets logged.